# Delleting each image from database

Tags: php, database

I'm writing a plugin and I have one problem. I want to make a button which will delete a row from my DB.

```
global $wpdb;

$links = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_jslider;");
if ($wpdb->num_rows==0) {
    echo 'No images, please upload';
}
else {
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        echo '<img src="'.$link->url.'">';
        echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST"><input type="submit" id="'.$link->id.'" value="Delete" name="del"></form>';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['del'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM wp_jslider WHERE id = $id");
    }
}
```

I can't create a delete button for each image. Any suggestion?

Comment: I guess you are a fan of SQL injection.

Answer (score -1):

This code should work:

```
global $wpdb;

$links = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_jslider;");
if ($wpdb->num_rows == 0) {
    echo 'No images, please upload.';
} else {
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        echo '<img src="'.$link->url.'">';
        echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST"><button type="submit" value="'.$link->id.'" name="del">Delete</button></form>';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['del'])) {
        $id = $_POST['del'];
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM wp_jslider WHERE id = $id");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the answer. The `value` of the button should be the id of the image you want to delete, not `Delete`.

Comment: It takes value of the value attribute,After reloading of the page!!! So SQL result is 'query("DELETE FROM wp_jslider WHERE id = Delete");'

Comment: besides the problem that it´s not working.... you should NEVEREVER use this code in production! It´s vulnerable to SQL injection cause you use an unverified user input for your SQL query. I guess all your $id values are numeric? So you should verifiy that $_POST['del'] only contains numeric vaules e.g. with a regex to provide basic protcetion against SQL injections. Otherwhise an attacker may delete content from your hole database and/or delete tables and/or steal (user) data!

Comment: Michael, I understand, but I have to start from something. I've just started learning php

Comment: Really - This answer has SQL injection as well. Sending del with the value "like '%'" will do wonders. And that is for starters

Comment: If I thought about it I could be the whole database emailed to me

Comment: I think this will fix injection issue
'if (isset($_POST['del'])) {
         $id = $_POST['del'];
         if (is_numeric($id)){
          global $wpdb;
          $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM wp_jslider WHERE id = $id");
         }
     }'